# Expose every replica pods in a deployment/replicaset with nodeport service

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset, kubernetes-service

I have 2 bare metal worker nodes and a replicaset with 10 pod replicas. How can I expose each pod using nodeport?

Comment: Hi, What is the use-case for doing this, instead of a simple deployment with 10 replicas, and a NodePort service?

Comment: I could expose the service with nodeport, but I need each pod exposed on different ports of a worker. Each pod requires an individual port. 
Usecase: I am using it for RDP port. @WytrzymałyWiktor

Comment: Kubernetes pods are ephemeral, so I'm not sure your approach is recommended. 
Maybe [kubectl port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward) is what you need ?

Comment: Sorry for late, but to follow up this, I created the pods using **podantiaffinity** to make sure only one pod they gets scheduled on one node. And using nodeport. I can access each pods separately from nodeport exposed for each nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `kubectl expose` command to create a `NodePort` `Service` for a `ReplicaSet`.

This is a template that may be useful:

```
kubectl expose rs <REPLICASET_NAME> --port=<PORT> --target-port=<TARGET_PORT> --type=NodePort
```

The most important flags are:
**NOTE:** Detailed information on this command can be found in the [Kubectl Reference Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose).

***--port***

> The port that the service should serve on. Copied from the resource being exposed, if unspecified

***--target-port***

> Name or number for the port on the container that the service should direct traffic to. Optional.

***--type***

> Type for this service: ClusterIP, NodePort, LoadBalancer, or ExternalName. Default is 'ClusterIP'.

I will create an example to illustrate how it works

---

First, I created a simple `app-1` `ReplicaSet`:

```
$ cat app-1-rs.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: app-1
  labels:
    app: app-1
spec:
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx

$ kubectl apply -f app-1-rs.yaml
replicaset.apps/app-1 created

$ kubectl get rs
NAME    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
app-1   10        10        10      93s
```

Then I used the `kubectl expose` command to create a `NodePort` `Service` for the `app-1` `ReplicaSet`:

```
### kubectl expose rs <REPLICASET_NAME> --port=<PORT> --target-port=<TARGET_PORT> --type=NodePort

$ kubectl expose rs app-1 --port=80 --type=NodePort
service/app-1 exposed

$ kubectl get svc app-1
NAME    TYPE       CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
app-1   NodePort   10.8.6.92    <none>        80:32275/TCP   18s

$ kubectl describe svc app-1 | grep -i endpoints
Endpoints:                10.4.0.15:80,10.4.0.16:80,10.4.0.17:80 + 7 more...
```

If you want to make some modifications before creating the `Service`, you can export the `Service` defintion to a manifest file and apply it after the modifications:

```
kubectl expose rs app-1 --port=80 --type=NodePort --dry-run=client -oyaml > app-1-svc.yaml
```

---

Additionally, it's worth considering if you can use `Deployment` instead of directly using `ReplicaSet`. As we can find in the [Kubernetes ReplicaSet documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#when-to-use-a-replicaset):

> Deployment is a higher-level concept that manages ReplicaSets and provides declarative updates to Pods along with a lot of other useful features. Therefore, we recommend using Deployments instead of directly using ReplicaSets, unless you require custom update orchestration or don't require updates at all.

Comment: I could expose the service with nodeport, but I need each pod exposed on different ports of a worker. @matt_j

Answer (score 0):

you can create a service with selector point to the pods, use NodePort type, and be sure deploy kube-proxy on every node.

example yaml like below, you should set right selector and port. get service detail for nodePort after created

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

the official doc is good enough https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/